# How can I install a driver using Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, driver, inno-setup

I'd like to install a driver for a serial port using Inno Setup. I have the `inf` file, and I can install the driver manually through device manager, but I'd like to be able to include the driver in my installer so that users don't have to go through the trouble of installing the driver themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [`InstallHinfSection` in Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-installhinfsectionw). The documentation also mentions how to invoke an installation by calling `Rundll32.exe`. Probably you'll end up with something like this:

```
[Files]
..
Source: "driver\my_x86driver.inf"; DestDir: {app}\driver;
Source: "driver\my_x86driver.sys"; DestDir: {app}\driver;

[Run]
..
Filename: {sys}\rundll32.exe; \
    Parameters: "setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 128 {app}\driver\my_x86driver.inf"; \
    WorkingDir: {app}\driver; Flags: 32bit;
```

---

Note that you might need to run the setup in 64bit mode in 64bit systems to be able to install the driver:

```
[Setup]
..
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

Also you can put checks as to run the version of `.inf` file depending on machine architecture (e.g. `Check: Is64BitInstallMode`).

Comment: The 64 bit mode of InnoSetup does *not* produce a 64-bit installer executable! You need to use a small helper 64 bit executable just to invoke the needed API. The APIs to use are `UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices` on XP, and `DiInstallDriver` on anything past XP.

Answer (score 6):

This is a better answer: [Install drivers with rundll32 or dpinst in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864549/install-drivers-with-rundll32-or-dpinst-in-inno-setup)

Using `InstallHinfSection` on Windows 7 and beyond seems to be either broken or fraught with difficulty. Making it work from a batch file is difficult, making it work from Inno Setup is even more difficult. `dpinst` seems preferable, and is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

I used dpinst like this:

```
 [Files]    
Source: "Source\dpinst\dpinst32.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\driver"; DestName: dpinst.exe; Check: not IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Source\dpinst\dpinst64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\driver"; DestName: dpinst.exe; Check: IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\driver\dpinst.exe"; Parameters: "/A /LM";
```