# Install drivers with rundll32 or dpinst in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, driver, inno-setup

I am trying to install drivers with Inno Setup and it looks like there are (at least) two ways to do this: add `dpinst.exe` to the or run `rundll` against the `.inf` file.

I know there is two different version of DPinst for x86 and x64. Are there different version depending on the OS (I need to support XP, Vista and 7)?

Do I need admin permission for these methods?

Which method is recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the same DPInst version for all versions of the operating systems; the only distinction is 32-bit vs. 64-bit. The WDK comes with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Personally, here's what I do (on InnoSetup):

```
[Files]
...
Source: ...\dpinst32.exe; DestDir: {#DpInstPath}; DestName: dpinst.exe; \
    Check: not IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: ...\dpinst64.exe; DestDir: {#DpInstPath}; DestName: dpinst.exe; \
    Check: IsWin64; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Using `run32dll setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection ...` is outdated and generally not recommended unless you have some very specific needs.

Comment: Starting in Windows 10 Version 1607 (Redstone 1), the Driver Install Frameworks (DIFx) tools are no longer included in the WDK.